# Errors in docker-compose file " stderr_lines": ["yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block collection"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Team

I have a docker compose file which throws below erros

```
fatal: [10.0.1.4]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "bash setup.sh\n", "delta": "0:00:00.629193", "end": "2021-08-18 20:53:27.578148", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2021-08-18 20:53:26.948955", "stderr": "yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block collection\n  in \"./docker-compose.yaml\", line 14, column 7\nexpected <block end>, but found '<scalar>'\n  in \"./docker-compose.yaml\", line 15, column 68", "stderr_lines": ["yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block collection", "  in \"./docker-compose.yaml\", line 14, column 7", "expected <block end>, but found '<scalar>'", "  in \"./docker-compose.yaml\", line 15, column 68"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Not sure where it's going wrong and below is my Docker-Compose file

```
version: '3.7'
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: vr0
services:
  demoproject:
    build: 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    volumes:
      - /usr/share/logData:/log
      - {{ wms_input_path | default('/opt/vr/demoproject/wms/input') }}:/wms/input
      - {{ wms_output_path | default('/opt/vr/demoproject/wms/output') }}:/wms/output
    restart: always
    labels:
      filebeat_enable:
    env_file:
      - ./.env
```

Comment: The `{{ wms_input_path ... }}` syntax isn't standard Docker Compose syntax.  Is something like Ansible launching this?

Comment: Yes Ansible is launching this.